# How do I generate declared files and directories using java_common.compile.annotation_processor_additional_outputs?

Tags: bazel

I use an annotation processor to generate language bindings from interfaces defined in Java. I want to replace actions created by `ctx.actions.run` with actions generated by `java_common.compile`, so that I can exploit Bazel's native support for persistent javac workers.

Here's a mockup of the original **working** Bazel rule implementation using `ctx.actions.run`:

```py
def _impl(ctx):
    output_dir = ctx.actions.declare_directory(output)
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add(output_dir.path, format = "-AoutputDir=%s")
    ctx.actions.run(
        ...,
        outputs = [output_dir],
        arguments = [args],
    )
    return DefaultInfo(files = depset([output_dir]))
```

What I'd now like to do is swap out `ctx.actions.run` with `java_common.compile`. Here's a mockup of what I've come up with:

```py
def _impl(ctx):
    output_dir = ctx.actions.declare_directory(output)
    java_common.compile(
        ...
        output = ctx.label.name + "-placeholder.jar",  # -proc:only
        javac_opts = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-AoutputDir={}".format(output_dir.path),
        ],
        plugins = [ctx.attr._emitter[JavaInfo]],
        annotation_processor_additional_outputs = [output_dir],
    )
    return DefaultInfo(files = depset([output_dir]))
```

Here's my problem: after building my target, `output_dir` is created but empty.  I'm able to locate my files in Bazel's output root by running `find -L bazel-out -name uniqueOutputDir`, but they're buried under `bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/my_packages/_javac/my_target/my_target-placeholder_sourcegenfiles/uniqueOutputDir`, and then rolled into `bazel-bin/my_package/my_target-placeholder-gensrc.jar`.

Any ideas? Like, how is `annotation_processor_additional_outputs` supposed to work? How can I specify via `javac_opts` to write directly to `output_dir.path` without the `...sourcegenfiles` prefix?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you checked https://source.bazel.build/search?q=annotation_processor_additional_outputs for example code?

Comment: It looks like additional inputs / outputs were added for processors that will output artifacts that are known ahead of time (added in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6415). If you can instruct your processor via flags to output specific files (a zip or jar), that could work with additional outputs. otherwise, would it make sense to extract your interfaces from gensrc.jar?

Comment: @Paul Yup! I've had luck in the past sussing out details from unit tests, but I struck out this time. (There's a Starlark analysis test in Java, but it wasn't specific enough to apply here.)

Comment: @AngusDavis Yeah, it looks like extraction is the way to go. I've found a solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convincing `java_compile` to let my processor emit directly to `output_dir` appears to be a non-starter.  (Output location seems to be governed by the Bazel-impl-defined [sourcegendir](https://source.bazel.build/search?q=sourcegendir&sq=).)

So with that in mind, after `java_common.compile`, I added an action which extracted my outputs from the generated source jar, and this appears to solve my problem.

```py
def _impl(ctx):
    output_dir = ctx.actions.declare_directory(output)
    java_common.compile(
        ...
        output = ctx.label.name + "-placeholder.jar",  # -proc:only
        javac_opts = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-AoutputDir={}".format(output_dir.basename),
        ],
        plugins = [ctx.attr._emitter[JavaInfo]],
        annotation_processor_additional_outputs = [output_dir],
    )

    extract_args = ctx.actions.args()
    extract_args.add(output_dir.dirname)
    extract_args.add(java_info.annotation_processing.source_jar)
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = [java_info.annotation_processing.source_jar],
        outputs = [output_dir],
        arguments = [extract_args],
        command = """
            set -euo pipefail
            output_root=$1
            gensrcjar=$2
            unzip -q -d $output_root $gensrcjar
        """,
    )
    return DefaultInfo(files = depset([output_dir]))
```